# Implementar con <iframe> vide de Youtube en silencio (muted)

Tags: html, wordpress, video, iframe

Tengo integrado una galeria de videos en wordpress con  he visto que hay muchas opciones para configurar estos videos pero no la opción de silenciarlos

```
    <iframe id="video" src="<?php echo $result; ?>?rel=0&vq=hd720&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=<?php echo $playlist[1]; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

El código php es porque no siempre es el mismo video sino como he dicho vá variando dependiendo el bloy y la galeria.

He visto tutoriales con muchas opciones pero no esta que necesito (http://leaderswest.com/2012/10/10/youtube-embed-options-can-make-your-videos-look-less-youtube-y/).

Comment: En la API de youtube tienes la función `mute()` :https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente la solución:

HTML Y PHP

```
<iframe id="video<?php echo $playlist[1]; ?>" class="video" src="<?php echo $result; ?>?rel=0?vq=hd1080&amp;autoplay=1&amp;hd=1&amp;playlist=<?php echo $playlist[1]; ?>;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var players;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    var players = document.querySelectorAll('.video')
    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        new YT.Player(players[i], {
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady
                    },
          videoId: players[i].dataset.id
        });
    }

}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.mute();
}
```

Gracias!